# Why does the Unanswered page need a no answers tab?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, no-answers

This tab seems a tad bit redundant...
[image: Needs more tabs.]

Perhaps it should be removed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because "Unanswered" contains questions with **no upvoted answers** and "no answers" contains questions with **really no answers**.

The explanation is actually in your screenshot on the right under the questions count.

Comment: That is very un-intuitive... And I didn't realize that phrase changes per tab. "Questions with no answers" seems perfectly reasonable for the top Unanswered tab.

Comment: Well, I agree. But you get used to it :)